# UINavigationBar custom transition animation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I've created custom transitions between view controllers using the following protocols:

`UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`

Is it possible using the default `UINavigationBar`, to create custom transitions for the titles, right now they simply crossfade between view controllers, Or do i have to built my own navigation bar view from scratch?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[WWDC 2013 video](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) #218 indicates that all custom transitions will crossfade the navigation bar, and that there's no way to customize this behavior.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that :) i was unsure if i simply formulated my searches on google wrong, since i couldnt get any results.

Comment: There is a site that transcribes all wwdc sessions. You can find the transcription of the 218 session here: http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/218

Comment: Any idea if this has changed since ? Is there still no way to customize the animation during transition if `UIBarButtonItems` ?

Comment: Regrettably, this has not changed since.

Comment: So, this is probably bad practice, but a semi-work around to at least change the duration of the crossfade is to set the transitionDuration time interval to whatever you want the crossfade to be, and manually use a different duration for your actual animations. I had a transitionDuration of 0.65 and that fade looked awful, so I set it to 0.2 and it looks better now.

Comment: If you're missing a way to opt in to the standard shift animation for custom transitions you might want to dupe my radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/23620167

Answer (score 3):

If your transition is both custom and interactive, then you can get some mileage out of `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator`.
see [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle).

For example, in `viewWillAppear` of the view controller that is the "To" (target) vc:

```
[[self transitionCoordinator] animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

    // mess around with stuff here

} completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

    // all done now
}];
```