# Custom transition between view controllers including navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm following [this guide](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html) to do a custom transition between two `UIViewControllers` that are within a navigation controller.

I'm trying to replicate the transition [this 'Storehouse' app transition](http://capptivate.co/2015/01/11/storehouse-3/) ,see the transition on the far left.

Notice that the transition includes the navigation bar. However, by default the transition only applies to the view UNDER the navigation bar and just crossfades the `UINavigation` bars between views.

I want a reference to the entire views including the navigation bar so that I can recreate this effect. I understand I'm probably seeing this behavior since they share a `UINavigationController`, and thus a navigation bar.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369046/push-pop-view-controller-with-navigation-bar-from-view-controller-without-navi/27748007#27748007)

This is a much asked question here on SO btw. Maybe use the search functionality first next time? ;)

**EDIT**

Reviewing the transition you posted I must say it does not look like this is a `UINavigationController` setup. The solution I linked above works for a default setup. It looks like 'Storehouse' has put up a custom solution here. (I looks very neat though!).
You will probably have to code this by yourself, i.e. fake the navigation bar.

Comment: You are correct, it looks like without 'faking' the navigation bar there is no way to do what 'Storehouse' did. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613682/uinavigationbar-custom-transition-animation